# Python bad character string 0x00

Tags: python, endianness

I am trying to run a program with user input as shown below. The objective is to replace a variable with \x8d\x12\x00\x00 (little endian). However, it ends up become 5600128d. Could anyone who can advice on this? Thanks very much

```
user@vm:/home/question$ ./run_me $(python3 -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'A' *1024 + b'\x8d\x12\x00\x00')")
```

-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

Jumping to function at 0x5600128d!!

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: You can't store arbitrary binary data in a shell string, as they are null-terminated. `bash` is telling you that the argument to `run_me` will end with `\x12`.

Comment: Right, because you can't pass null bytes through a command line parameter.  Are you writing malware here?

Comment: I count three different layers of command substitution at work here. To run a Python program. Perhaps you should start by dealing with *that* and the other string problems may disappear once you're not running things through an eldritch parser

Comment: @SilvioMayolo This doesn't actually have anything to do with the Python, though. A [mcve] for the same error would be `echo $(printf '\x00')`.

Comment: @TimRoberts No, i am doing some school assignment...

Comment: Well, the bottom line is you can't pass null characters through shell parameters.  You can write them to stdout, so you could have your Python script get piped into `run_me`.